# Splitting a very long string into rows AND columns

Tags: string, excel, parsing, data-cleaning

Using a very basic SQL-editor I have extracted a string of more or less the equivalent of 300,000 rows into the Mac Terminal. I want to split this very long string into both different rows (every entry has about 15 different elements, but are now all glued together in a string), and columns as well.

The data is currently formatted like this, with some of the sub-fields just one word, and others lengthy blocks of text:

> (u'A' u'B' u'C' u'dfhudhf isduh, fdiu fdjfoidjofiod' u'D'),(u'A' u'B' u'C' u'dfhudhf isduh, fdiu fdjfoidjofiod' u'D'), (u'A' u'B' u'C' u'dfhudhf isduh, fdiu fdjfoidjofiod' u'D') etc.

With `)' (` as the delimiter between different rows, and `u'` as the delimiter for different fields! Copying into Excel ends up just being one very long string and doesn't really listen to text-to-column commands.

I have been trying to split this in Excel, but I can't manage to make it work. If there is other software that is better to use, I am very willing to try that too!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your expected result (How it will look).

Comment: Its hard to know without seeing your file, but often Access is better equipped for dealing with data extracts - which may help with delimiting in both directions.

Comment: Could you post a worksheet with this string in cell A1 on a Dropbox share (or similar)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I am pasting a little subset below (unfortunately am not allowed to share the full dataset :(  ):

I want it to parse properly into an excel sheet (or become a CSV)  Thousands of lines like this, the data is clean otherwise:  

(u'0002-7820', u'1953; VOL 36; NUMBER 4', None, u'CERAMIC ABSTRACTS', u'53-74', u'E', u'EL', None), (u'0002-7820', u'1953; VOL 36; NUMBER 4', u'THORNTON, J. C.', u'Relation Between Bond and the Surface Physics of Masonry Units', u'105-120', u'E', u'16', u'3681721', u'EL', u'While the author and his (...) masonry units.'), (etc. etc.)

Comment: my goal is to ultimately upload all the data in R to analyze! Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know how it does.

This assumes your string is in cell A1 on the active worksheet.

This will process the string and output a table of data beginning in row 3 of the same sheet as the source string.

Place the following procedure in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub mouse()
    Dim i&, j&, s$, r, c, w
    s = Replace([a1], " ", "")
    r = Split(s, "),(")
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(r) + 1, 1 To 1000)
    For i = 0 To UBound(r)
        c = Split(r(i), "u'")
        For j = 1 To UBound(c)
            w(i + 1, j + 1) = Replace(Replace(c(j), "'", ""), ")", "")
        Next
    Next
    [a3].Resize(UBound(w, 1), UBound(w, 2)) = w
End Sub
```

Switch back to the sheet with the long string in cell A1.

Press Alt-F8 to open the Macro Dialog.

Run `mouse`.

Answer (score 0):

Much the same result at @Exel Hero (but preserving spaces) if copied into Word, replace `u'` with `^t`, replace `), (` with `^p` and Convert Text to Table... (probably default settings) then copy into Excel.